# Матлаб убрать одинаковые цифры внутри вектора

Tags: массивы, matlab

У меня есть матрица, например:

```
А = [1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 6]
```

И я хочу убрать повторяющиеся цифры вместе с самой цифрой, чтобы получилась другая матрица:

```
Б = [1 2 5 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Собственно код:

```
A = [1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 6]
n = unique(A)
for i = n
    id = ismember(A, i);
    if sum(id) > 1
        A(id) = [];
    end
end
A
```

Результат:

```
A =

     1     2     3     3     3     4     4     5     6


n =

     1     2     3     4     5     6


A =

     1     2     5     6
```